# LINQ to Entities: perform joins on many-to-many relationships (code first)

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities, code-first

I have the following model:

```
[Table("Experiments")]
public class Experiment
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<ExperimentType> ExperimentTypes { get; set; }

    public Experiment()
    {
        ExperimentTypes = new List<ExperimentType>();
    }
}

[Table("ExperimentTypes")]
public class ExperimentType
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Experiment> Experiments { get; set; }

    public ExperimentType()
    {
        Experiments = new List<Experiments>();
    }
}
```

The DbSet contains:

```
    public DbSet<Experiment> Experiments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExperimentType> ExperimentTypes{ get; set; }
```

And this creates a table on SQL, called ExperimentExperimentTypes.

Now, I would like to perform a LINQ join, like:

```
var query =
   from e in database.Experiments
   join eet in database.ExperimentExperimentTypes on eet.Experiment_Id equals eet.ExperimentType_Id ...
```

But obviously database.ExperimentExperimentTypes in not recognized in code.

I tried a lot of things in order to tell the code that there is this table, I also tried to create the corresponding c# class, but I'm not getting any result.

How can achieve that?

Comment: Just use the navigation properties and it will create all the needed joins.

Comment: *"But obviously database.ExperimentExperimentTypes in not recognized in code."*; if the table is there, you can define it in code. That way it is accessible. Depending on your query, and doing it correctly, you can boost performance that way.

Comment: (in addition to my previous comment): or do what @juharr said ;-)

Answer (score 1):

So you have two tables: `Experiment` and `ExperimentType`. There is a many-to-many relation between those two: every `Experiment` is an experiment of zero or more `ExperimentTypes`; every `ExperimentType` is the type of zero or more `Experiments`.

This many-to-many can be seen in your class definitions. The `virtual ICollection<...>` on both sides indicates the many-to-many relationship.

In relational databases this many-to-many relation is implemented using a junction table. However, in entity framework you seldom see the junction table. It is in your database, however, you can't access it using your DbContext

> But how am I going to perform a join between Experiments and
> ExperimentTypes if I can't access the junction table?

Well, Pooh bear should go back to his thinking spot. You don't want to join tables, you want `Experiments`, each with its `ExperimentTypes`.

So why not just do the query using the `ICollection<...>`?

```
var experiments = myDbContext.Experiments
    .Where(experiment => ...)              // only if you don't want all experiments
    .Select(experiment => new
    {   // Select only the properties you actually plan to use
        Id = experiment.Id,
        Name = experiment.Name,
        ...

        // get all or some of its ExperimentTypes
        ExperimentTypes = experiment.ExperimentTypes
             .Where(experimentType => ...)  // only if you don't want all experiment types
             .Select(experimentType => new
             {
                  // again: select only the properties you plan to use
                  Id = experimentType.Id,
                  ...
             })
             .ToList(),
    });
```

Entity framework knows the many-to-many, it knows that for this a triple join with the junction table is needed, and will perform this triple join.

Internally this will be a **GroupJoin**, you'll get `Experiments`, each with their `ExperimentTypes`. You even get Experiments that don't have any ExperimentType yet.

If you really want the `inner join`, you'll have to flatten the Experiments with their ExperimentTypes. This is done using the [overload of SelectMany that has a resultSelector as parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___System_Func___0___1___2__)

```
// flatten the Experiments with their experimentTypes
var flatInnerJoin = myDbContext.Experiments.SelectMany(experiment => experiment.ExperimentTypes,

    // from each experiment and one of its experimentTypes make one new object
    (experiment, experimentType) => new
    {
        ExperimentId = experiment.Id,
        ExperimentTypeId = experimentType.Id,
        ...
     });
 })
```

Nota bene! This way you won't get the Experiments that have no ExperimentTypes, just as in a standard inner join.